# Making Array From Page Elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

I have a huge HTML select list that has a bunch of options. Some of the options have a 'parent' attribute which I'm using to identify. Basically, when someone picks the parent dropdown, all of it's children populate a different dropdown. So I'm trying to place all of these objects into an array, remove them from the page and then call them when I need them.

This is all HTML code that I've taken from a site we're working with so they make it work somehow themselves (not sure how though). My thought was just to make an object and push the items into that object (with keys of 'id' and 'parent'). It doesn't seem to work the way I'm doing it though:

```
var location_array = new Object();

$('select[name="location"] option').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('parent')){
        var obj = {
            id: $(this).attr('id')
            parent: $(this).attr('parent')
        }
        location_array.push(obj);           
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know this is probably pretty basic but I don't do this type of coding very often. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is `parent` an attribute in HTML ?

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAkbar, I'd never seen it but it was able to grab the attribute. Like I said, I copied the code from another page that has working code and I was able to use console.log to print out the 'parent' value on all of the options, so it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
var location_array = new Object();
```

to

```
var location_array = [];
```

Object has no method `.push()`

Answer (score 0):

You're using `push`, but `location_array` isn't an array, it's an object.

I would probably keep it an object (I've changed the name):

```
var parents = {}; // A better way to write `new Object()`

$('select[name="location"] option').each(function(){
  var parent = $(this).attr('parent');
  parents[this.id] = parent;
});
```

Now you have a map, mapping element IDs to their parents. (Note that `$(this).attr("id")` is just a really roundabout way of writing `this.id`.)

---

Side note: When using custom attributes, stick with [the `data-*` prefix](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) to avoid conflicts with HTML-defined attributes (now and in the future).